# Extended Desktop to Mac book from Macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display

I have two Mac one is mac book and other Is Mac book Pro and i am looking for a way so i can use macbook as a extended Monitor for MAc BOok Pro.

is there a way to do it .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is likely not supported.

[This article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924#1) (apple.com) says how to use an iMac as a second display but makes no mention of using a MacBook(Pro) as one. Which usually means it is not supported.